# Security issues with using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Basically, i want to ask if anyone had security isses with Yii Framework when creating large-scale e-commerce projects. My client whants this framework to be used in this project and with my previous experience of working with Symfony I want to double check this question.

Yii is cool and it is getting popular. [Yii popularity article](http://www.zfort.com/blog/why-is-yii-framework-getting-great-popularity/). But there's always a "What if" question and I want my client to be sure that all his data is safe. And to be sure myself as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yii as a framework itself is secure:

```
Yii is equipped with many security measures to help prevent your Web applications
from attacks such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site
request forgery (CSRF), and cookie tampering.
```

From the [Yii features page](http://www.yiiframework.com/features/)

But it comes down to the developer to ensure that everything is secure. Check out this these posts on writing secure Yii applications:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/273/yii-security-extended-guide/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security